# Is there a more efficient way using mysql to get a list for a given column in an sql result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that rows of a table each containing an id.

For each id I want to get multiple values from another table.

The way I would do this is make the first query, then loop through the result making a query for each id.

This could mean making a thousand queries, is there a way I could do this in 1 query.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `group_concat()`.  Something like this:

```
select t1.id, group_concat(t2.othercol) 
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id;
```

Or perhaps you just want `in`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.id in (select t1.id from table1 t1);
```